# Installing/Configuring PHP to work with tomcat5 and mysql on CentOS

Tags: php, mysql, tomcat, centos

I need to install php on a CentOS machine and configure it to work with tomcat5 and mysql

Anyone know how i can do this?

the home folder for tomcat and mysql is

```
/usr/share/tomcat5
/usr/share/mysql
```

for php, I downloaded from
http://php.net/downloads.php,
PHP 5.3.10 (tar.gz)

i extracted the files php source to

```
/usr/local/src/php-5.3.10
```

Now I'm unsure on how to proceed with the installation of php to work with tomcat5 and mysql..

Need help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to run PHP on Tomcat?